# How to add specific subfolder of subrepo

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I'm comming from SVN background and I'm having a problem of adding to my main repo a subfolder of subrepo. That means that I don't want to add the whole subrepo to my main project - only a part of it. In my situation I want to include only source files of my library excluding all unit tests.

I have created .hgsub file and wrote there:

```
libs/my_std_lib = https://myreposhost.com/my_std_lib_repo/src/main/java/
```

But when I'm trying to synchronize libs/my_std_lib folder I get such error: `HTTP Error: 404 (Not Found)`

When I try to synchronize without subpath (`https://myreposhost.com/my_std_lib_repo/`) - it works well.

So what do I do wrong or this is not posible in hg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple : it's impossible to clone only a part of a repository with Mercurial.

By extension, you can't add only a part of a repository as a subrepo.

Sorry.

Comment: OK, so that means that I will have to divide my library into separate repos and that join it into one. Inreption... :)